# How do tear glands secrete tears?

Tags: human-biology

Keep in mind I'm not asking what the function of tears are or what causes tearing,(there's a lot of good answers on it already). My question is: how exactly is the tear gland able to actively push out fluids when it receives a stimuli? What exactly is the tear gland doing and how does it produce tears? How does it start and stop?